# Math operations with Date object and <input type="time">

Tags: javascript, html, object, tags

How to make possible to use math operations in JS between the data from Date object and the data from  string ("hh:mm") from HTML?

The code is expeted to make a countdown from the entered time in  field to the current time using getHours, getMinutes and getSeconds methods. Or it is better to use some other tags and/or methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a jQuery plugin in order to make the countdown after you have got the data from the field? Have a look at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html.

**EDIT:**

I used the following JS code to make http://jsfiddle.net/oxnmvhLc/2/:

```
function startCountdown(nowObj, timeObj) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var nowObj = new Date();
        if(nowObj > timeObj) {
            timeObj.setDate(timeObj.getDate() + 1);
        }
        var difference = (timeObj - nowObj) / 1000;
        var seconds = Math.floor(difference % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((difference/60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((difference/3600) % 24);
        $('#countdown').html('There are ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes and ' + seconds + ' seconds.');
    }, 1000);
}

$('#btn').click(function() {
    var time = $('#time').val().split(':');
    var nowObj = new Date();
    var timeObj = new Date(nowObj.getFullYear(), nowObj.getMonth(), nowObj.getDate(), time[0], time[1], 0, 0);
    $('#countdown').html('');
    startCountdown(nowObj, timeObj);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, but the essential point is to make a countdown without any frameworks. I want to use only JS to understand all the process from inside.

Comment: OK, in that case, could you give a more specific example of what you wish to achieve.

Comment: It should be something like below. When you choose some time in <input type=“time”> then starts JS. It takes the chosen time string (e.g. "15:45") and then starts countdown from the current time. If you entered 15:45 and current time is 12:00, JS takes the difference (3:45) and starts countdown: "3h 44m left", "3h 43m left" and so on.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer, I believe I have implemented what you wanted. If you like it, could you please +1 and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Zak What's with the `console.log`s?

Comment: Sorry, just for testing, will take them out.

Comment: @Zak, thanks, it will help. I can't +1 your answer, because the site says, vote up requires 15 reputation. I marked your answer as accepted.